# MSE loss with PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

I have some trained models with their corresponding MSE, which has been computed using the nn.MSELoss function of PyTorch. [You can see the plot here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAzwJ.png)

When I test the models and I calculate the MSE without the built-in function, I get [the plot that can be seen here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnzEw.png). It has a lot of peaks and it is no longer smooth.

To calculate the MSE, I am using this formula (with numpy as np):

```
mse = np.mean((Cp_train - Cp_train_predicted)**2)
```

where `Cp_train` is my ground truth vector and `Cp_train_predicted`is my array of predictions.

As far as I now, it should give the same results as if I had used the built-in function in training. Did I misunderstand the internal working of MSELoss?

Comment: Do they both have the same shape? You can check with `print(Cp_train.shape, Cp_train_predicted.shape)`. The prediction might be a 1D array whereas the input is a  vector/matrix, resulting in broadcasting.

Comment: Hi Muhammed, thanks for your quick response! Yes, both are 371x49574 arrays.

Comment: No worries. I am not sure what the problem is - if you could provide some code that replicates this behaviour, that would help with identifying the issue. If you calculate both MSEs at the same time, and print them out e.g. `print(mse_torch.item(), mse_numpy)`, what does that show?

Comment: I'd say easiest way to debug is to make some dummy tensors and see how MSE works on those. Are you accounting for the batch dimension too? It'd be something I look at.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error, and it has nothing to do with the way of computing MSE. After Cp_train, there is an intermediate variable from which you compute Cp_train_predicted. I sort that variable to plot it, but it does not have to be changed to calculate Cp_train_predicted. That was the error, I was using the sorted variable to calculate my predictions. Such a little error. Anyway, thank you all for your replies! :D